# Converting survival analysis by a continuous variable to categorical so as to find level of most significant difference

Tags: r, survival

I am doing a survival analysis by a continuous variable using:

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(Survival, Dead) ~ HighestKi67, data = SurvivalbyHighestKi67)
fit
```

which returns:

```
               coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z        p
HighestKi67 0.12152   1.12921  0.02582 4.706 2.53e-06

Likelihood ratio test=15.9  on 1 df, p=6.666e-05
n= 160, number of events= 56
```

I want to represent this graphically so I thought to separate the continuous variable into 2 categories (less than *X* VS greater than *X*) and plot on a K-M plot

So my question is this: other than trial and error, how could I find the cut-off value(X) that would maximise the significant difference between the two categories?

More generally, is there another way to graphically represent survival analysis of a continuous variable?

With thanks,

Comment: EdM mentions the rms package authored by Frank Harrell. Although Frank does not sanction categorizing predictors as you suggest, he does presnt the hazard ratios for comparison of individuals at the 25th percentile and the 75th percentiles of predictor distributions.It would be somewhat similar to comparing the lowest tertile (lower third) to the highest tertile (upper third) for the predictor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to " maximize the significant difference between the two categories." There is much than can be lost when you try to [categorize a continuous predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/28500). The best cutoff found from your data probably wouldn't be the best cutoff in a new set of data.

There are two approaches that can accomplish what you need without leading to unrealistic expectations about performance on new data.

For *display only*, not for establishing "significance," you can simply choose a reasonable cutoff that illustrates the survival difference. The median predictor value is often used. If there's bi-modality in the distribution of predictor values, you could use a cutoff at the dip in the distribution between the two modes. Explain clearly to your audience what you did, and emphasize that the "significance" of your result is based on the continuous modeling, not on this display.

A second approach is to plot the hazard ratio and its confidence limits as a continuous function of the predictor value. There are software tools that can help with that display, like the `Predict()` function in the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R. That has the advantage of displaying precisely what you modeled.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a frequent problem in survival analysis. The main variable of interest is continuous, but you still want a Kaplan-Meier style plot to display the main effect. Instead of artificially categorizing your continuous variable or displaying conditional effects (as the `rms` package does), you could use the `contsurvplot` R-package (written by me). It produces plots that display the counterfactual survival probabiltiy both as a function of time and the continuous covariate. More information can be found in the preprint that I recently published: https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.04644

It can be installed directly from github using:

```
devtools::install_github("RobinDenz1/contsurvplot")
```

I will give a quick example using the `nafld1` dataset from the `survival` package. Suppose we are interested in the effect of age on the survival time. We first use a Cox model to analyze this effect:

```
library(contsurvplot)
library(riskRegression)
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(pammtools)

# using data from the survival package
data(nafld, package="survival")

# taking a random sample to keep the example fast
set.seed(43)
nafld1 <- nafld1[sample(nrow(nafld1), 400), ]

# fit cox-model with age
model <- coxph(Surv(futime, status) ~ age, data=nafld1, x=TRUE)
```

Now we want to visualize the effect for 40 to 70 year olds. We can easily create a survival area plot using the `plot_surv_area` function:

```
plot_surv_area(time="futime",
               status="status",
               variable="age",
               data=nafld1,
               model=model,
               horizon=seq(40, 70, 0.5))
```

[image: survival area plot]
Or we can use a survival contour plot:

```
plot_surv_contour(time="futime",
                  status="status",
                  variable="age",
                  data=nafld1,
                  model=model,
                  horizon=seq(40, 70, 0.5))
```

[image: survival contour plot]
In my opinion, both are better options than simple categorized Kaplan-Meier plots.

Comment: (+1) Nice figures!